# How to terminate the execution of all python files in one project?

Tags: python

I have two running python files in one project: client & server and I need to terminate the execution of both of them (client & server) from inside the server code.

Comment: Can you provide us with code of what you made so far ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.